# Obtaining help on functions with IntelliJIdea

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm beginning to use IntelliJIdea, but some things are not so easy as in Eclipse. 
How can I find help for a function in IntelliJIdea? I need to know what will do a function and know his parameters, but I can't find the way to know how.

For example:

```
espacioJuego.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v) {
         int elementoX= v.getX() <----- I need help on this
      }
  });
```

(This is only an example. I know what getX does)

Comment: ctrl+space to autocomplete, double ctrl+space do autocomplete + docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl + space for auto-complete. Ctrl + P to see arguments

At first I thought like you. I liked Eclipse and IntelliJ was so strange that I started hating it.

But as soon as I get used to it, I fell in love with IntelliJ. I recommend you to take a look to the [Keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) and use some plugins as [Key Promoter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1003).

You'll soon learn how to get the best from IntelliJ

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.